# How to create an Excel chart showing data over 24hrs

Tags: excel

I have a data set that includes only two columns - errtype (A,B,C) and errtime (hh,mm,ss). This data is being collected over many days. I want to create a graph that will make it easy to discern when, with a 24hr day, most errors are occurring and what type of error they are. I don't want to aggregate the data points into hourly groups if it can be avoided. It's been easy enough to create a bar chart that shows the errors with time of day across the x axis. The bar heights themselves almost never exceed 1 on the x axis unless more than one errtype occurs at the exact same second. For this reason I don't think a scatterplot would look all that good even if I could figure out how to do that type of grpah. With the bar chart style, what I can't figure out is how to get the y scale to be 24hrs in Excel. There doesn't seem to be an option for it in the bar chart axis properties, even when I've set the data type as "time".

Answer (score 0):

When i want to accomplish a timeline it has involved the creation of an artificial table showing the data with the expected grain (for example 1440 rows for all the minutes in one day) and then use a vertical lookup to get the corresponding value to that time.

After being bored of doing this manually for different types of grains, you can even get into adjusting the size of the table automatically which is actually kind a cool

I do not have an example with me right now, but if this question is still not answered tomorrow i will give you a complete dummy example of how to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure if artificially creating data is the right approach. I thought about doing that and just adding an artificial 00:00:00 and 23:59:00 entry, but thought there must be a way to set the x-axis scale. Is there not?